# Running Linux command from Java - runtime.exe

Tags: java, linux, find, command, runtime

I'm trying to run the following command using Java runtime:

```
find /home/Alison/workspace/FunctionalTestFramework/src/com/q1labs/qa/selenium/screens -type d |   awk -F/ 'NF <= old_NF {print prev} {old_NF=NF; prev=$0} END {print $0}'
```

The command works fine when entered directly into a Terminal but when ran in the following function it gives the following error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
Process exitValue: 1
```

The Java function:

```
     try
        {            
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("find /home/Alison/workspace/FunctionalTestFramework/src/com/q1labs/qa/selenium/screens -type d |   awk -F/ 'NF <= old_NF {print prev} {old_NF=NF; prev=$0} END {print $0}'");
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
        } catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: I would suggest coding your specific shell script, and run that script from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, you could `exec` a shell, e.g. `/bin/sh` with `-c` followed by the string to interpret. This is what the [system(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/system.3.html) function in standard C does on Unix & Posix systems.

However, I would just suggest to write a shell script doing what your complex command does, and exec that shell script. This gives the ability to (test and to) improve that shell script without changing your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
rt.exec("find /home/Alison/workspace/FunctionalTestFramework/src/com/q1labs/qa/selenium/screens -type d |   awk -F/ 'NF <= old_NF {print prev} {old_NF=NF; prev=$0} END {print $0}'");
```

by this:

```
rt.exec(new String[]{"find", "/home/Alison/workspace/FunctionalTestFramework/src/com/q1labs/qa/selenium/screens", "-type", "d"});
```

Note that you will not be able to run any command that uses a pipe `|` because redirection operators like pipes are a shell feature, but the command passed to exec() isn't run in a command shell.

Comment: You could exec a shell, e.g. `/bin/sh` with `-c`  followed by the string to interpret. This is what the `system(3)`  function in standard C does on Unix & Posix systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you put that as an answer as it worked, thanks.